# MvvmCross ViewModel class with Init() method crashes at design time

Tags: mvvmcross

I try to implement design time data into my code (see DataContext below).
The problem is, I have an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in visual studio with MainView.xaml opened in design view. I tried to debug it with another VS instance  but got no breakpoints. 
I narrowed it down. As soon as there is an Init() method on the ViewModel something fails. This Init() is being called by the MvvmCross framework.
If I remove the Init() method it works very well in Designer. So, I suspect MvvmCross is missing a "IsInDesignMode" check, but since I'm new to MvvmCross it may be very likely my fault.

Full sample is here:
https://github.com/indazoo/MvvmCross_DesignData
This sample throws the exception. You can remove the Init() method in MainViewModel.cs and the code runs fine in Designer.

To debug the designer I disabled "Just my code" and enabled all CLR exceptions in the attaching VS instance but got no breakpoints. Any tips welcome.

Here some code excerpt (more in the sample code on github):

The page is derived from LayoutAwarePage (MvvmCross TipCalc Sample).

```
<localViews:LayoutAwarePage
x:Class="App2.MainView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2"
xmlns:localViews="using:App2.Views"
xmlns:cirrViews="using:Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DesignFactory}, Converter={StaticResource DesignConverter}, ConverterParameter=MainViewModel}"
>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="1234"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="123123"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DesignTimeHello, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=DesgnRuntimeFallback}" FontSize="30" />
        <TextBlock Text="123123"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=FallBackTextBox}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind of XAML:

```
    public sealed partial class MainView : LayoutAwarePage
{
    public MainView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public new MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (MainViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel:

```
    public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private IDataService Data { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel(IDataService data) 
    {
        Data = data; 
    }

    public string DesignTimeHello
    {
        get { return Data != null ? Data.TestData : "Missing"; }
    }


    //!!! If you comment this method everything works !!!
    public void Init()
    {
        int i = 0;
        i++;
     }
     .....
```

App.Xaml

```
<Application
x:Class="App2.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:CoreHelpers="using:App2.Helpers"
xmlns:local="using:App2">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <CoreHelpers:DesignTimeHelper x:Key="DesignTime" />
        <local:DesignFactory x:Key="DesignFactory"/>
        <local:DesignTimeConverter x:Key="DesignConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```